# Determine if a script is running in pythonw?

Tags: python, pythonw

I would like to redirect `stderr` and `stdout` to files when run inside of `pythonw`. How can I determine whether a script is running in `pythonw` or in `python`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sys.executable` -- "A string giving the name of the executable binary for the Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense."

Comment: On my mac it says `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python` (which does make perfect sense) whether I run python or pythonw.

Comment: The Mac doesn't need Pythonw anymore (since 2.3). Pythonw is only interesting for windows developers anymore.

Comment: I don't think that is true about Macs. I have some issues that are only resolved by using pythonw.

Comment: This does not work on Mac becasue pythonw sets the environment variable PYTHONEXECUTABLE to point to the regular python script.